# Can't install any packages on Natty Server

Tags: server, 11.04, apt

Can't install upgrade or update any...

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

--

```
 E: Unable to locate package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm add into `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

then apply `sudo apt-get -y update`
This solve my problem